# Access won't change or delete relationships

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a database with 8 tables. The 2 I'm interested in is 'catelogue' and 'tracklisting'. Originally when I built the DB I thought the best way to releat the catelogue table to tracklisting was on the catalogue no. of said product eg. CDRPM 1254. Since then I have decided and learn't the better way to do this is on the primary Key ID. I have added a new feild to my tracklisting table called 'Look Up To Cat'. The feild used before to refernce was called  'TRACKLISTING_CAT_NO.' After changing the relationship from catelogue.Cat_No. - tracklisting.TRACKLISTING_CAT_NO. to catelogue.ID - tracklisting.Look Up To Cat, the catelogue table was still using the old join.

I'm using access 2007, the join is a one-to-many. When I delete the TRACKLISTING_CAT_NO. feild then I get enter parameter for that feild dialogue box, because now it's referencing a feild that dosent exsit.

I have deleted the relationship, edited it, compacted and repaired the db. NOTHING has helped. I have googled this too and to no avail.

A Huge thanks in an advance to any one that helps

Comment: Is `look up to cat` a look-up field in the table?

Comment: no it's just a normal field that I'm trying to join

Comment: I created a new database but access still sees the old join. I think this has to do with the orinal way the db was imported from excel and then split in access. After many hours of rebuilding, this morning access decided to lose 8000 tracklistings. I have since moved now to mysql with a backup of my db and am building my own insert forms and such. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

the problem appears to be in a query, not in a table. Check your queries for the `JOIN` and alter it to point at your new field